# Configure monitor orientation through GPO?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Is it possible to force a particular monitor orientation through a GPO?

I've got a bunch of Windows 7 PC's that are used for displays, and I'd like to be able to drop a computer into a group that forces it to adopt a 'Portrait' monitor orientation when it's logged in. However, I can't seem to find anything in my GPO editor. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. I had to write my own .NET program that takes in some arguments about screen resolution and orientation, and then calls the Win32 `ChangeDisplaySettings` method. I then set this application as a startup script for a particular OU and I end up with a PC that switches it's orientation on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised to hear that video card manufacturers would have a plugin so that their driver can be controlled with active directory/GPO? I guess Intel would be your best bet.

Alternatively, there might be command-line interfaces to drivers:
Matrox used to heave great command-line interfaces for their drivers, but AFAIK, nVidia and ATI never did.

I suspect your best bet would be to hook up with a developer to expose driver API's as command-line tools, and then you can script and automate.

Comment: I wouldn't have expected to have to dig into the drivers, given that that monitor orientation selection is a standard feature in Windows 7.

Comment: Given Microsoft's 30+ year track record, I'd be surprised if the latest eye-candy has a management back-end :-/ Hopefully there's some powershell commands you can use to control the monitor orientation.